# How can I join on only a certain number of rows

Tags: sql

I want to join two tables on a particular column, but I only want to join on 50 of the rows from the first table. I.e. I want to do the following:

```
select * from s1.companies c limit 50 join s2.employees e on c.id = e.c_id;
```

I'm getting a syntax error because of the limit. How can I do this query? The reason I want to do this is because the companies table has millions of rows and I just want to play with some of the data without having long running queries.

Comment: What db are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subquery.

```
select * from (select * from s1.companies limit 50) c join s2.employees e on c.id = e.c_id;
```